# Power BI Report Approval Workflow

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

In Power BI, when a report is set as discoverable, users without permissions are prompted to submit a request, (typically to the report owner.)

However, my department never gives direct access to a report. Instead, we distribute all reports through a workspace app, where your AAD security group determines your audience, which in turn determines the reports you receive. This can be confusing for the requestor, since we have to reject their request for direct access, then add them to a security group and instruct them to ignore the initial rejection email.

Is there a way to customize the approval process for Power BI reports? My current solution is to route all requests to a shared mailbox, which sends an autoreply and triggers a flow in Power Automate. Ideally, however, we could customize the request form in Power BI.

Is anyone aware of a solution like this? Perhaps a tenant admin setting?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try not setting the reports themselves as discoverable and instead focus on the making the app discoverable.
Also maybe create a simple report (outside of the app) that is also discoverable and accessible to all, with instructions to how to then get approval to the app.